# OSGi Containers

Tags: osgi, containers, apache-karaf

What is most usable OSGi container? I've been using [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/) lately, but I would like to know what container do you recommend the most from your experience?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a good question. *Most usable* is very subjective. You should specify your requirements. Are there any specific points you are not happy with in Karaf? Have you tried any other OSGi containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Karaf is my favorite because of the great console and deployment from maven repos. It is also very nicely integrated with other apache projects. So installing camel, cxf or activemq is really easy.